# Nautilus: Copy to same dir name gives a whacky sort sequence: (copy) (another copy) (3rd copy). I want 001, 002

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, filenames, nautilus

I am using GNU/Linux Ubuntu 10.4 
  ... the `"GNU"` should keep Richard Stallman happy; and reasonably so :)

The file browser, Nautilus, generates `"reading-friendly"` names for files which are copied into their own source directory.  The result of copying `MyFile` three times is:

```
MyFile
MyFile (3rd copy)
MyFile (another copy)
MyFile (copy)
```

These above result is a list which is chronologically out of sequence.
Is there some way to change this behaviour, so the the resulting filenames are like this:

```
MyFile
MyFile.001
MyFile.002
MyFile.003
```

All suggestions are welcome, thanks.

PS. I don't want to sort by created or modified-date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to change that behavior, but usually such repetitive operations are better performed with scripting.

Comment: (my username seems to have gone walkabout, but anyhow..)  Re. scripting... Well, I realize that the Linux mind-set is quite creative with names, eg. the classic "GNU"... and I actualy think that "(another copy)" is quite amusing, but it doesn't suit me.  Also, being Linux, there may well be an underlying normal geeky-numbers-only logic, with this version as a mod... I hope so... Yes, the scripting would work, but I'd still prefer an integrated solution.  Even Windows Explorer's demented magic-sort algorithms have an "off" registry setting. Maybe Ubuntu has a similar Off-switch. (else Python?)

Comment: If so, maybe you should try messing around with [gconf-editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gconf-editor).